# my foreign key isnt working?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having an issue with my tables, the first table creates a reference to the data in the second table, the CARD_ID increments fine, but the foreign key in CARD_INFO_TABLE isnt autoincrementing or even realising it is a foreign key of an autoincrement, So i would just like to know, where am I going wrong!?

```
    public static final String CREATE_CARD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CARD_TABLE + "(" + CARD_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + CARD_NAME
        + " TEXT )";

    public static final String CREATE_CARDINFO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CARD_INFO_TABLE + "(" + CARD_ID2
        + " INTEGER, " + CARD_NAME2
        + " TEXT, " + CARD_WEIGHT
        + " REAL, " + CARD_REPS
        + " INTEGER, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY " + "("+ CARD_ID2 +")"+ " REFERENCES " + CARD_TABLE + "("+CARD_ID+"));";
```

and then I insert data to them as follows, where am I going wrong??

```
public void insertEntry(String name, double weight, int reps) {
    if(flag == 0) {
        open();
        database.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_NAME, name);

        // Insert the row into your table
        database.insert(DataBaseHelper.CARD_TABLE, null, newValues);
        flag = 1;
        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
        close();
    }
    open();
    database.beginTransaction();
    ContentValues newValues2 = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues2.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_NAME2, name);
    newValues2.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_WEIGHT, weight);
    newValues2.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_REPS, reps);

    // Insert the row into your table
    database.insert(DataBaseHelper.CARD_INFO_TABLE, null, newValues2);
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    close();
}
```

Comment: Why should a row that is inserted in a different transaction, in a different database connection, have any relation to some other row? Anyway, the FOREIGN KEY declaration is a *constraint*; it justs adds more checks to the database.

Comment: I thought the foreign key would read the highest number from the primary key and use that to add data to the CARD_ID2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [foreign key constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) is just a constraint, i.e., it just checks that the changes you are doing to the data do not create wrong relationships.

To create those relationships, you still need to insert the same data (and you should not needlessly split the operation into two transactions, and you must correctly handle exceptions):

```java
database.beginTransaction();
try {
    long cardID = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(database,
                    "SELECT "+CARD_ID+" FROM "+CARD_TABLE+
                    " WHERE "+CARD_NAME+" = ?",
                    new String[] { name });
    if (cardID < 0) { // not found?
        ContentValues card = new ContentValues();
        card.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_NAME, name);
        cardID = database.insert(DataBaseHelper.CARD_TABLE, null, card);
    }

    ContentValues info = new ContentValues();
    info.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_ID2, cardID);
    info.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_NAME2, name);
    info.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_WEIGHT, weight);
    info.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_REPS, reps);
    database.insert(DataBaseHelper.CARD_INFO_TABLE, null, info);

    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    database.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer, but wouldnt this add data to the CARD_TABLE each time?

Comment: Yes. This is just example code. You haven't specified what `flag` is.

Comment: Very sorry, basically I have a class with a name and a List in it, so I wanted one table to hold the name and the ID, and another table to hold each of the items of the List, and have the foreign key be the highest of the primary key

Comment: If you don't want to insert a new row into the card table, get the appropriate ID with a query.